# Which GCP solution should be used for an infinite-lifespan/long-running process?

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I'm currently hosting on Heroku, which handles long-running processes in a way that requires explicit code changes to put things into a job queue. I don't want to do explicit code changes like a job queue, so I want to move this particular block out.

I have a `Gmail.users.watch` email watcher running on there, and I'd like to move it over to GCP because Heroku seems to run into `R15 - Vastly exceeded memory quota` errors with my code. I believe it's because for every request that Heroku handles, it spawns a new instance of the long-running `Gmail.users.watch` process. (EDIT: just kidding it's a memory leak)

```js
const beginWatcher = () => {
    gmail.users.watch(
        {
            auth: authClient,
            userId: "me",
            requestBody: {
                topicName: topicURL,
                labelIds: ["INBOX"]
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                return
            }
        }
    )
}

beginWatcher()
```

I have not got a lot of GCP from-scratch experience, I'd like to know;

1. **Where does a long running process like the above fit in GCP?**

   - Google App Engine seems to be basically Heroku, but I believe a single instance of a server is what I need for something that will run forever like the above code.
   - Google Compute Engine seems to be a single VM that starts up, but also seems to be used for heavy compute loads instead of just an email watcher, so it might be overkill.
   - Google Kubernetes Engine seems to handle hosting with Docker in mind, but this seems overly complex to use for something like this, since I have to specify pretty much everything.
2. **Should I be using another GCP solution that is not one of the above three?**

My gut tells me Google Compute Engine, but I just want someone to confirm for me; **where the heck do you put an infinite-lifespan process like this in GCP**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose Google Compute Engine you will probably incur some unwanted overhead for managing your own VM. It shouldn't be that complex for the use case you've described but it could create some unwanted surprises.
The upside of using a VM is that you could solve your memory leak by either implementing some kind of garbage collector that will clean up dead processes or even restart the machine every once in a while.

Having said that, the real solution to your issue would probably be solving the memory leak you are experiencing. In most cases this will require less effort then moving your app to a new platform.